# Modelmetadata for sorting properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any way of setting sort order of my properties with model metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/11/Ordering-fields-in-ASPNET-MVC-2-templated-helpers.aspx) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As I know there no easy way to do that. You can override model meta data provider with your customized one via deriving from default metadata provider and apply your sorting method.

```
protected  void Application_Start()
{
    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new ConventionMetadataProvider();
    ModelValidatorProviders.Current = new ConventionValidatorProvider();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Here is nice [post](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/customizing-asp-net-mvc-2-metadata-and-validation.aspx).